# Create a matrix by crossing a list

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

I've a list `L` of elements. I want to create a matrix by laying each elements of L in both rows and columns where each `cell[i,j] = f[L[[i]], L[[j]]]`

I am not getting a way to create a matrix with given list. Here `L` is a string list obtained by `StringSplit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
L = StringSplit["I want to create a matrix by laying"]
```

> {"I", "want", "to", "create", "a", "matrix", "by", "laying"}

```
Outer[f, L, L] // TableForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]